# Row Editing with Primefaces has old value when listening for change

Tags: primefaces

this is my code:

```
...
private List<Erfasst> alle;

public List<Erfasst> getAlle() {
    if (alle == null) {
        return alleEintraege.alle();
    } else {
        return alle;
    }
}
```

....

The Function is in a @ApplicationScope Class.

My ajax function which listens to the edit row looks like this:

```
public void bearbeiten(RowEditEvent event) {
    neuerEintrag.aendern((Erfasst) event.getObject());

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Objekt geändert");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

My problem is, that the event Object always gets the old value and not the new value. So what's wrong?

Comment: Do you use component  `<p:cellEditor>`? See example: 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

Comment: post your XHTML as well.

Comment: This is not deterministic question, too many variables, post you XHTML, state your PF version... please provide an MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example